# Can mock automatically instantiate mock objects?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm writing tests for the class `OnlineService` which instantiates a class of type `api.API`, which in turn instantiates a class of type `api.Resource`. The method I'm testing in this example is `initialize` which tests connectivity with the remote service, by issuing a `GET` request to a `Ping` resource in the remote API.

I'm currently patching these objects to be mocks using the following code, but it still looks a bit verbose to me.

```
@patch('api.Resource')
@patch('api.API')
def test_initialize(self, api_mock, resource_mock):
    api_instance = api_mock.return_value
    api_instance.Ping = resource_mock.return_value # is this step really necessary?
    api_instance.Ping.get.side_effect = [None, HTTPError()]

    service = OnlineService()

    service.initialize()
    assert service.connected is True

    service.initialize()
    assert service.connected is False
```

Do I really have to assign a `Resource` mock instance to the property of another mock instance manually? Perhaps there is some feature in the `mock` package that can do this for me?

**UPDATE**

I've split up the test in two and also attached the relevant code from the `OnlineService` that is under test. Here is the `OnlineService` class:

```
class OnlineService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.webservice_url = u''
        self.verify_ssl = True
        self.connected = False

    def initialize(self, webservice_url, verify_ssl, connectivity_check_timeout):
        self.webservice_url = webservice_url
        self.verify_ssl = verify_ssl
        self.connected = self.can_connect_to_api(connectivity_check_timeout)

    def can_connect_to_api(self, connectivity_check_timeout):
        api_instance = api.API(url=self.webservice_url, verify_ssl=self.verify_ssl, timeout=connectivity_check_timeout)
        try:
            # api_instance.Ping of type api.Resource was instantiated in api.API()
            api_instance.Ping.get()
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

And here is the test code:

```
def test_initialize(self):
    service = OnlineService()
    service.can_connect_to_api = MagicMock(return_value=True)

    service.initialize(u'some_url', False, 3.42)

    service.can_connect_to_api.assert_called_once_with(3.42)
    assert service.webservice_url is u'some_url'
    assert service.verify_ssl is False
    assert service.connected is True

@patch('api.Resource')
@patch('api.API')
def test_can_connect_to_api(self, api_mock, resource_mock):
    api_instance = api_mock.return_value
    api_instance.Ping = resource_mock.return_value # is this step really necessary?
    api_instance.Ping.get.side_effect = [None, HTTPError()]

    service = OnlineService()

    connected = service.can_connect_to_api(5.0)
    assert connected is True

    connected = service.can_connect_to_api(5.0)
    assert connected is False
```

Currently the test passes if I run it. Commenting out the line we're discussing gives me the following failure in `test_can_connect_to_api`:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: Services.tests.test_OnlineService.TestOnlineService.test_can_connect_to_api
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Development\Projects\app\venv\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Development\Projects\app\venv\lib\site-packages\mock.py", line 1201, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "C:\Development\Projects\app\src\Services\tests\test_OnlineService.py", line 47, in test_can_connect_to_api
    assert connected is False
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.013s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Please don't put 'SOLVED' sections in your question; that's what the accept mark is for. :-)

Comment: But the exact code you used **doesn't matter** to future visitors. It is the *concepts* that matter here; my answer told you how to solve your specific problem, because I explained how the mechanics work.

Comment: If future visitors cannot work out that `@patch('module_under_test.API')` is the solution here because I didn't use the exact module name your code used, then they won't be able to figure that out with your now-working code either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
api_instance.Ping = resource_mock.return_value # is this step really necessary?
```

assigns a new empty `MagicMock` instance to `api_instance.Ping`. However, accessing `Ping` without that assignment *already* does this because `api_instance` is itself a `MagicMock` object; the line is entirely redundant:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> api_instance = MagicMock()
>>> api_instance.Ping
<MagicMock name='mock.Ping' id='4515362016'>
```

As such, the following would suffice:

```
@patch('api.API')
def test_initialize(self, api_mock):
    api_instance = api_mock.return_value
    api_instance.Ping.get.side_effect = [None, HTTPError()]
```

Of course, if the code-under-test is *not* using `api.API().Ping.get` to obtain the resource, then the above code would not achieve its goal; but then you won't need to alter `api_instance.Ping` *either*.

The thing to remember here is that you *replaced `api.API`*; what that class original does is no longer of concern to you. All you need to do is manage the expectation of the code *using* `api.API`; if it uses `api.API()` and uses attributes or methods on that object, mock those out. If `api.Resource` is not directly used by the code-under-test, leave it out of your tests too.

Your added code shows that you are *mocking the wrong object* however. You mocked `api.Resource` correctly, but theh `API()` object in the CUT is **not a mock**. See the [*Where to patch* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) of the `unittest.mock` documentation. Your CUT uses a global name `API`; it does **not** reference `api.API`. Mock *that global*:

```
@patch('module_under_test.API')
def test_initialize(self, api_mock):
    api_instance = api_mock.return_value
    api_instance.Ping.get.side_effect = [None, HTTPError()]
```

or you could just have mocked out *just* the `Ping` resource; evidently that is what your unmocked `API()` class uses, after all:

```
@patch('api.Resource')
def test_can_connect_to_api(self, resource_mock):
    # API().Ping is an instance of api.Resource; mocking that also works
    resource_mock.return_value.get.side_effect = [None, HTTPError()]
```

Comment: The CUT instantiates `api.API` (which implicitly instantiates a bunch of `api.Resource` objects, of which `Ping` is one) and then calls `get` on the `Resource` instance `Ping`. So I can't leave it out of the test.

More importantly, since `Ping` is instantiated by `api.API`'s constructor, the line doesn't seem redundant to me, since `MagicMock` won't instantiate `Ping` for me. Is there some trick I can use for this? Or should I leave the method as is?

Comment: @Korijn: but it *is*; `api.API()` is now a mock. Whatever the original did, that *doesn't happen anymore nor does it matter*. What does the code in the CUT *look like* when it uses `Ping.get`?

Comment: @Korijn: You are mocking the **wrong `API` object**. You need to mock `module_under_test.API`, not `api.API`.

Comment: @Korijn: because you did not mock the correct `API` object, your *original API class* is now using the mocked `api.Resource` object. The line is still redundant; so is the use of `api_mock` in that case.

Comment: That solved the issue. New insights are abound. One last question; which of the two classes would you prefer to mock (`API`/`Resource`) and why?

Comment: @Korijn: For unittests I'd mock `API()` as that is the boundary between the CUT and the outside world. This is not an integration test between the CUT and the API object, after all.